# Software or tools recommended to improve fast your C++ programming skills

Tags: c++

List anything you think is great to improve c++ knowledge...   Please be concrete when giving solutions.

Comment: This should be 'community wiki' as it is clearly not a question seeking a concrete valid answer. --Edit the question an select the 'community wiki' tick

Comment: I am seeking concrete answers, because I am asking for people to recommend me software, tools, websites to practice and improve my c++ skills, and I already took three c++ course.  I just want concrete problems that I can access through the web and use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1)** Daily Read c++ , stl and related tagged question on stackoverflow , Try **analyze** the 
       problems , **think** of **solution** , and **understand** solution given by others

**2)** :) **Start working** on C++ in you work , If you have good senior people who do a 
       strict **code/design review** and give valid comments , you will learn c++.

**3)** Participate on **open source projects** , Download source and analyze it.

**4** Regarding tool : Use source code analyzer like [coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) , Lean **window debugging** tools package or something equivalent in unix,

Answer (score 3):

Mark C++ as a favorite tag on stackoverflow, and read anything that was answered by litb.
Seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Learning a language that has many different ways to solve the same problem, a wealth of undefined behavior, keywords that have multiple context-dependent meanings and an ambiguous grammar will never be fast.

Start with Scott Meyer's Effective C++.

Answer (score 1):

Spend some time studying the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/) (or buy the book and read it).  Thinking about and understanding the answers there has helped me learn a lot about C++.

Answer (score 0):

The ones I know for C++ are OGRE 3D for game development and online judges for practicing software development.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to help you improve:

- Read lots of books (like the one Brad mentioned)
- Read lots of code
- Write lots of code
- Be open to looking at a problem from
  a new viewpoint

Comment: I would like to add: Continue reading more code.

Answer (score 0):

- First, assess your self, either do a mockup test or something to know where you stand.
- Take a course in advanced C++. Algorithms, data structures, networking, or any other class where they'll give you a huge project to work on and where you'll be graded on your code, and the knowledge of C++ is expected.
- buy a Solved problems book for C++, I recommend "how to program C++" (The problems and solutions edition) by Deitel and Dietel. Some might not recommend D & D but for your purposes, it's adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking in C++ by Bruce Eckel

They are free downloads now: http://www.mindview.net/Books/DownloadSites

A legendary book in my opinion. Eckel is a clear and concise author.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Amazon, find some "learning C++" books with high ratings, read the reviews and see which ones best meet your needs, buy two or three, and work through them.

However, I'd be careful about "C++ How to Program" by Deitel and Deitel. Early editions were fantastic, but I find the sixth edition too bloated and wordy for pedagogical purposes, and next to useless as a reference. Maybe the seventh edition is better, but I couldn't say.

You might also be able to find some good online courses. MIT's OpenCourseWare site might have something useful.

But don't believe anybody if they promise you can start from knowing nothing and become a C++ guru in 21 days or something. I've been programming mainly in C++ for nineteen years and don't consider myself a guru yet.

Answer (score 0):

As the shoe salesman said: Just Do It.

Simply put, just start coding and you'll soon find out what you need to know. You can read all the books in the world, but until you can apply knowledge it's worthless.